# Declaring React state, in constructor, versus out of constructor

Tags: reactjs, components, state

Is there any difference of declaring `state`, *out of constructor*?

I have an example of a component here:

```js
class BurgerBuilder extends Component {
  state = {
    ingredients: {
      salad: 0,
      bacon: 0,
      cheese: 0,
      meat: 0
    },
    totalPrice: 30
  };
  ....
}
```

Here I just declare a variable called state, which includes the variables of the component, *but I don't call a constructor.*

Where as i declare:

```js
class BurgerBuilder extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      ingredients: {
        salad: 0,
        bacon: 0,
        cheese: 0,
        meat: 0
      },
      totalPrice: 30
    };
  }
  ....
}
```

I found, that I can use `this.setState` for both solutions and that there is no real difference in my project. Is there a best practice, on what to use where.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any difference? Is there a best practice, on what to use
>   where?

They're almost the same. The syntax for declaring the `state` without `contructor()` is [*syntactic sugar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

---

What you're using in the first example is called [Class field declarations](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#class-field-declarations-for-javascript). (This proposal reached Stage 3 in July 2017).

In short, this proposal allows us a simpler syntax for declaring class fields, without the need for the `constructor()`.

For example, those codes are written using ES2015

```js
class Counter extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onclick = this.clicked.bind(this);
    this.x = 0;
  }

  clicked() {
    this.x++;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
  }

  connectedCallback() { this.render(); }

  render() {
    this.textContent = this.x.toString();
  }
}
window.customElements.define('num-counter', Counter);
```

By using [Class field declarations](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#class-field-declarations-for-javascript), they will be like this:

```js
class Counter extends HTMLElement {
  x = 0;

  clicked() {
    this.x++;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onclick = this.clicked.bind(this);
  }

  connectedCallback() { this.render(); }

  render() {
    this.textContent = this.x.toString();
  }
}
window.customElements.define('num-counter', Counter);
```

The benefits of using this syntax:

> By declaring fields up-front, class definitions become more
>   self-documenting; instances go through fewer state transitions, as
>   declared fields are always present.

---

Reference: [Class field declarations for JavaScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#a-guiding-example-custom-elements-with-classes)